# How to start from previous step in python web-application?

Tags: python

I am designing a web-application on Python-pyramid. Web-application involves 3 step to create report.

- In first step, User enters details and files to analyze. Web-application does pre-processing and displays option/parameters taken from files. It takes a min to analyze.
- In second-step, Users has to select options/parameters and submit it. Web-application will process files based on this input.
- In step three, web-application gives a download report link and sends a mail.

My problem is in step one. It may happen, that user has left browser unattended and session has expired. So when he login again, what is best way to show his previous work? I am thinking of storing processed objects on disk using pickle. Then on step 2 I can show him list of previous work request user want to proceed.

Are there any better approach than this?

Comment: Don't store them on the disk using pickle, store them in a database instead and use an ORM.

Comment: Security-wise, it's a bad idea to use [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html), see the big red warning on top of the module documentation. It's not safe to process untrusted user data with pickle, and that's exactly what you'd be doing here. Use a DB like @André suggested, or maybe a [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) file if you need something lightweight.

Comment: Thanks, as suggested will use database with ORM.